# How can I map a List which contains entities of same type as of parent type using Fluent NHibernate?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have an entity like this

```
public class Person
{
    public virtual int Pkey { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }

    public List<Person> Friends{ get; set; }
}
```

and its table information is like this

```
create table Person
(
    PKey int not null IDENTITY,
    Name varchar (20),
    primary key (PKey)
)
```

To get list of Friends, I am maintaining another table like this

```
Create table Friends
(
     PKey int not null IDENTITY,
     PersonFKey int not null Foreign key references Person(PKey),
     FriendFKey int not null Foreign key references Person(PKey)
)
```

Now when I do mapping like as below, I am getting some error (because of mapping problem)

```
 public class PersonMap :  ClassMap<Person>
 {
    public PersonMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Pkey);
        Map(x => x.Name);
        HasManyToMany(x => x.Friends).Cascade.All().Table("Friends").ParentKeyColumn("PersonFKey");
    }
 }
```

Exception thrown is,

```
FluentConfigurationException: "An invalid or incomplete configuration was used while creating a SessionFactory. Check PotentialReasons collection, and InnerException for more detail."
```

With inner exception,

```
InvalidProxyTypeException: The following types may not be used as proxies:

FluentNhibernateLearning.Entities.Person: method get_Friends should be 'public/protected virtual' or 'protected internal virtual'
FluentNhibernateLearning.Entities.Person: method set_Friends should be 'public/protected virtual' or 'protected internal virtual'
```

Can anyone help me pointing what I am missing?

Comment: Any reason you didn't try doing as the exception indicated and simply change to `public virtual List<Person> Friends { get; set; }`?

Answer (score 4):

You didn't state what the error was and the mapping doesn't match the classes, but I think the problem is that you are missing the `ChildKeyColumn` declaration. In a many-to-many map you have to declare the parent and child key columns; the parent key is the primary key from the class containing the collection and the child key is the primary key of the class in the collection.

Also, you almost never want cascading for a many-to-many as this would cause deletes to delete all the related entities. That is, deleting a person would delete all their friends.

```
 public class IntermediaryMap :  ClassMap<Intermediary>
 {
    public IntermediaryMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Pkey);
        Map(x => x.Name);
        HasManyToMany(x => x.SubBrokers).Table("Intermediary2SubBroker")
            .ParentKeyColumn("IntermediaryFKey")
            .ChildKeyColumn("SubBrokerFKey")
            .AsSet();
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to declare Friends as **virtual**.

That's what the Inner Exception message is telling you when it says:

"method get_Friends should be '**public**/protected **virtual**' or 'protected internal virtual'"